# How to remove projects/ solutions from Recent Projects window in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

In the top left corned of the Visual Studio Start Page there is a Recent Projects section that lists as standard 10 last opened Project. I am aware that this number can be changed using **Tools->Options->Environment->Genera**l and then modifying number in Recent Files section

But my question is how could I remove some projects from that recent list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [blog post](http://aspnetcoe.wordpress.com/2007/02/06/how-to-remove-recent-projects-from-visual-studio-start-page/) answers your question quite nicely. I won't duplicate the author's work here.

#### Steps to Remove Recent Projects

1. Close Visual Studio if it is running.
2. Start the Registry Editor (Start...Run... type `regedit`).
3. Navigate to this registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\ProjectMRUList`
4. Then delete the key that has the project you do not want to keep in the list.

Comment: Thanks, I must say that the first thing I was doing I was trying to do a right click to get a context menu with remove option :)

Comment: I know this is an old post... but do you know if there is any way to access this with the Visual Studio SDK; rather than editing the registry?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the Solution icon in Solution Explorer window, change the name of the Solution to a different one. Then double click the project in Recent Projects window. Visual Studio will ask you if you need to delete the project. Click OK to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an answer for people who are using Visual Studio for Mac:

> In the menu bar, choose *Files* ➞ *Recent Solutions* ➞ *Clear*.

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67203/how-do-remove-projects-from-welcome-page-xamrian-studio-for-mac